# How can I extend my French working holiday visa?

Tags: visa, france, working-holiday-visas

I am a Canadian. Currently, I am on a WHV for 1 year. I want to extend it for another year, and it is said to be possible on the Government web site. Has anyone successfully done so? If yes, where did you go to extend your visa?

Answer (score 1):

If the [French embassy in Canada](https://ca.ambafrance.org/Mobilite-des-jeunes-des-demarches-simplifiees-pour-venir-en-France) is to be believed, your WHV can actually be extended for one year (and once again for a total maximum of 36 months).

> A l’expiration de son visa délivré par le Consulat, le jeune canadien
> devra se rendre à la préfecture de son lieu de résidence et solliciter
> l’autorisation de prolonger son séjour dans le cadre de l’accord
> franco-canadien d’échange de jeunes de 2013.
>
> La préfecture délivrera alors une carte de séjour temporaire d’une
> durée maximum de 12 mois pour les jeunes professionnels (mention :
> travailleur temporaire), pour les étudiants (mention : étudiant) et
> pour les stagiaires (mention : stagiaire).

You need to find the "Bureau des étrangers" ou "Service des étrangers" of the *préfecture* or *sous-préfecture* from which you depend (ie depending on where you are living in France). Be aware that some of these offices are quite busy and getting an appointment might take some time.